# Adding event listener to multiple child components or simple parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have a parent component that renders multiple child components.  Each of these child components should be re-rendering themselves on every window resize event.

I'm wondering if it is better React practice to:

1. Attach event listeners to `componentDidMount` in each child component, as it is the child components' responsibility to listen to this event.
2. Attach a single event listenet to the `componentDidMount` of the parent component, and force its children to re-render when this event fires.

From a performance standpoint, I think #2 is better, but from a React-methodology standpoint, I think #1 is better.  Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds similar to the example of lifting state in the react docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of react is re-rendering a component (and its children) every time you change its state or props.

```
this.setState({isResized: true}); //trigger the rendering
```

you don't have to deal with the resize inside every child, just handle the window resize (maybe with a proper debounce to improve the performance) in the parent component and set a state consequently, the children will be re-rendered without any additional code.

something like this should work

```
class ParentComponent extends Component{

 resizeCallback(e){
  this.setState({'isResized', true}); //re-render even MyChildComponent
 }
 componentDidMount(){
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeCallback);
   //alternatively with underscorejs debounce
   //window.addEventListener("resize", _.debounce(this.resizeCallback, 300));
 }
 componentWillUnmount(){
   window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeCallback);
 }
 render(){
   <div>
     <MyChildComponent/>
   </div>
 }
}
```